# How to configure two routers to be connected with each other?

Tags: routing, router

I have configured a network environment, as below screenshot. Now I want the laptop n5 to connect to n10. When I run the traceroute command, it shows that the n5 can only reach to router n8. How can I let the router n8 connect to the router n1?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to run a routing protocol between the two routers so that they can share routes, or you need to put static routes on each router pointing to the other router for routes on the other router.

Static routes don't scale. Using a routing protocol can automatically share routes.

You will probably learn RIP first. Something like this on each router:

```
router rip
 version 2
 no auto-summary
 network 10.0.0.0
```

Comment: thanks for reply. I know the RIP principle. Do you know how to configure it on core network-emulator?

Comment: No, I don't. What I gave you was for Cisco routers, so if the emulator emulates those, that will work. RIP, OSPF, etc should all work for you. You can also do it with static routes, but if you grow your network, that will become a pain.

Comment: @ZhaoYi, also, the key to using RIP is that you run version 2 and disable the auto summary, otherwise both routers will think they know all about the `10.0.0.0/8` network, but you have it chopped up.